# How should I interpret a symmetrical autocorrelation plot?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation

I have plotted a time series using pandas autocorrelation_plot and mathplotlibs acorr.

[image: Mathplotlib acorr plot]

Notice that the above mathplotlibs image is symmetrical, what would this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autocorrelation is the cross correlation of a signal with itself. Unlike the cross correlation between two *different* signals, the autocorrelation is always symmetric about zero (i.e. equal at lags $+\tau$ and $-\tau$). Because the positive and negative halves of the autocorrelation function are redundant, sometimes only the positive half is plotted, as in your first plot. If you plotted the negative half as well, it would be symmetric like your second plot.

Comment: (+1) Otherwise put, the correlation between some $x$ at time $t$ and at time $t + \tau$ is identical to the correlation between those quantities the other way round, just as the correlation between $x$ and $y$ is the same as that between $y$ and $x$. The detail that there are some $t$ without a corresponding $t + \tau$ is solved by the correlation being defined only when both values are present (as is also true for $x$ and $y$, as in real datasets missing values are always possible). It's the same story if you think in terms of $t$ and $t - \tau$.